# ComboBoxCellEditor - get rid of the text box?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, tablecelleditor, tableviewer

I have a `TableViewer` with a `ComboBoxCellEditor`. When I click into the cell, first I get a text box (similar to the `TextCellEditor`) with an arrow next to it. If I click the arrow, I get the drop down list with the values I put into it.

Is there any way for me to skip the text box step? I want it to open up the combo box right away when I click/traverse into the cell. Hand in hand with this is that I also don't want to allow any options other than the ones in the list.

I thought maybe this behavior is controlled by a style, but the only styles I found were

```
/**
 * The list is dropped down when the activation is done through the mouse
 */
public static final int DROP_DOWN_ON_MOUSE_ACTIVATION = 1;

/**
 * The list is dropped down when the activation is done through the keyboard
 */
public static final int DROP_DOWN_ON_KEY_ACTIVATION = 1 << 1;

/**
 * The list is dropped down when the activation is done without
 * ui-interaction
 */
public static final int DROP_DOWN_ON_PROGRAMMATIC_ACTIVATION = 1 << 2;

/**
 * The list is dropped down when the activation is done by traversing from
 * cell to cell
 */
public static final int DROP_DOWN_ON_TRAVERSE_ACTIVATION = 1 << 3;
```

and they didn't seem to be relevant. In fact, I set all of them, and I wasn't able to get the functionality I'm looking for.

How can I have the dropbox show without having the accompanying text box?

Comment: [JComboBox#setPopupVisible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setPopupVisible(boolean))

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks. But I'm using the swt classes. The `ComboBoxCellEditor` uses a `CCombo`. This is a great idea though. I'm checking if it has any methods that I can use.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to change the styling of the underlying Combo widget by using the constructor:

```
ComboBoxCellEditor(Composite parent, String[] items, int style)
```

and passing `SWT.READ_ONLY` as style